# Log validation warning in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to log in mongoDB warning messages created by validation issues.
The steps are detailed below.
I can't make that work. It seems that nothing is caught even if invalid object is added to test_asaf collection.

Any hint will be appreciated.

Best,
Asaf

1. created a collection for the validation messages that are caught:

```
db.createCollection("validationWarnings")
```

2. added a validator to a collection with action type "warn":

```
db.createCollection("test_asaf", {
   validator: {
      $jsonSchema: {
         bsonType: "object",
         title: "Student Object Validation",
         required: [ "username", "email", "first_name" ],
         properties: {
            username: {
               bsonType: "string",
               description: "'username' must be a string and is required"
            },
            email: {
               bsonType: "int",
               description: "'email' must be an integer in [ 2017, 3017 ] and is required"
            },
            first_name: {
               bsonType: "string",
               description: "'first_name' must be a string if the field exists"
            },
            last_name: {
               bsonType: "string",
               description: "'last_name' must be a string if the field exists"
            },
            password: {
               bsonType: "string",
               description: "'password' must be a string if the field exists"
            }
         }
      }
   },
  validationAction: "warn"
} )
```

3. created a watcher that should "catch" the warning to a stream:

```
const changeStream = db.test_asaf.watch([
  { $match: {
      "operationType": "invalidate",
      "fullDocument.validationAction": "warn"
    } }
])
```

4. any message in the stream is sent to the validation warnings collection by:

```
changeStream.on("change", (change) => {
  const warningMessage = change.fullDocument; // Assuming the warning messages are stored in the fullDocument field
  db.validationWarnings.insert(warningMessage); // Insert the warning message into the separate collection
})
```

Comment: operationType [invalidate](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/reference/change-events/invalidate/) is not what you think it is. Failing schema validation doesn't emit change stream event.